# Debian 6.0 and Intel "Sandy Bridge" (DH67CL) integrated video

Tags: debian, xorg, video

Is there a way to get the above to work - I have a quite recent desktop with the hardware and OS mentioned in the title. I was in a rush when first installing it, so I just grabbed an nvidia PCI-e adapter since the **Sandy Bridge** onboard video did not work out of the box (I think I only got VESA video in X).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the "testing" repositories to your system and update.

```
sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
```

you should have something like :

```
#
# squeeze
#
deb     ftp://ftp.kulnet.kuleuven.ac.be/debian     squeeze main contrib non-free
deb-src ftp://ftp.kulnet.kuleuven.ac.be/debian     squeeze main contrib non-free
deb ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian squeeze main contrib non-free
#
#  Security updates - Uncomment to enable.
#
 deb     http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates  main contrib non-free
 deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates  main contrib non-free
```

now you change squeeze to testing behind each of them :)

```
 #
    # squeeze
    #
    deb     ftp://ftp.kulnet.kuleuven.ac.be/debian     testing main contrib non-free 
    deb-src ftp://ftp.kulnet.kuleuven.ac.be/debian     testing main contrib non-free 
    deb ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free 
    #
    #  Security updates - Uncomment to enable.
    #
     deb     http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates  main contrib non-free 
     deb-src http://security.debian.org/ testing/updates  main contrib non-free
```

`aptitude update, aptitude upgrade,apt-get dist-upgrade` and see what it gives. The drivers aren't issued in stable yet if I recall correctly